# CSS border-bottom-left-radius not applying in mozilla in a :before part

Tags: css

I face an error using my website on firefox.

When I want to use   border-bottom-left-radius in this specific tag it does not work

```
.faq-qa .faq-answer:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: -2px;
  right: -8px;
  height: 19px;
  border-right: 20px solid var(--green-color);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px 24px;

  transform: translate(0, -2px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -2px);

  transform: rotate(55deg) scaleX(-1);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(55deg) scaleX(-1);
}
```

I tried out the border-bottom-left-radius in an isolated case to see if it works (because according to [this mozzilla devs site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-bottom-left-radius) it should. And it did.

```
.test-border {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px 24px;
}
```

I think it can have something to do with `:before` because mainly thats the only difference between my normal code and my test code, but I don't know what could I use to solv this. I found a similar error at this site

https://codepen.io/AllThingsSmitty/pen/jommGQ

When I open the link in chrome or edge it looks like a nice chat bubble, but when I open it in firefox the arrow stuff is simple not the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50641793/firefox-css-border-radius-issue-for-pseudo-element-before

Comment: Yes thank you! Don't know why I didn't found it myself.